# MATLAB overload parentheses in a class instance

Tags: matlab

```matlab
classdef Dog
    methods
        function bark(obj, text)
            disp(text)
        end
    end
end
```

Suppose `d = Dog()`. Is there a way to make `d("woof")` be same as `d.bark("woof")`? Can the behavior of `d()` be changed in any other way?

In Python, that's overloading `__call__`.

Comment: In MATLAB, `()` on an object is indexing. Overload indexing by defining `subsref` (and `subsasgn` for the indexed assignment). I’m not sure if you can pass any string as an index though. I have never tried this.

Comment: In your deleted answer: “subsref also overloads . and {}, so this won't work.” You need to check what type of indexing it is, do your thing if it’s parenthesis, or call the base function if it’s not. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html#bu7rrk_ … except you can simplify that significantly because you don’t want to overload most of those cases.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for this, very helpful. How would I "call the base function if it's not"?

Comment: `builtin('subsref',obj,x)` it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [subsref](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) controls `()` behavior.
2. `d(x)` passes `x` to `subsref`, wrapped inside a `struct`.
3. Unpack as `x.subs{1}` and do anything, including returning an output.
4. `subsref` also controls `{}` and `.`; redirect these to its [native implementation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html#bu7rrk_).
5. MATLAB recommends a [mixin class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.indexing.redefinesparen-class.html), but that seems overkill.

Thanks to @CrisLuengo for the pointers. If anyone has more info, feel free to share.

```matlab
classdef Dog
    methods
        function bark(obj, text)
            disp(text)
        end

        function varargout = subsref(obj, x)
            if x(1).type == "()" && length(x) == 1 && ~isempty(x.subs)
                [varargout{1:nargout}] = obj.bark(x.subs{1});
            else
                [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, x);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice! So this works with arbitrary stuff inside the parenthesis? You can “index” with a string? Fantastic!

Comment: Aside; you can use `x = cellstr(x);` to output a cell array of chars regardless whether the input `x` is a char or a cell, removing the need for the class-check `if` condition

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks, though the intent is to output a cell array, consistent with `varargout`, where `= x` can be anything. Anything shorter for that?

Comment: @Wolfie `[varargout{1:nargout}] = ` appears to do it (and yes I changed `= x`).