# MATLAB `builtin` calls overloaded function

Tags: matlab

```matlab
% Dog.m -------------------------------------------------
classdef Dog
    methods
        function varargout = subsref(obj, x)
            varargout = subsref_overloaded(obj, x);
        end
    end
end
```

```matlab
% subsref_overloaded.m ----------------------------------
function varargout = subsref_overloaded(obj, x)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, x);
end
```

`d=Dog()`, and `d()` yields

```matlab
Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached.

Error in Dog (line 2)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, x);

Caused by:
    Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached.
```

Why, and can it be fixed? It's strange since it copies code straight from [implementation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html#bu7rrk_), and in debugger, `builtin('subsref', obj, x)` called while in `Dog.m` works as expected, but not while in `subsref_overloaded.m`.

---

**Context**: I'm overloading `subsref` [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73521919/10133797), but that's verbose to reuse so I want to make something like `subsref_overloaded(obj, x, fn)` and output `fn(x)`.

Comment: I think `subsref_overloaded` must be a class method for `builtin` to work. If so, you could make it a private function of your class.

Comment: @CrisLuengo As in the same class? That seems to defeat the purpose for reuse. I tried `SubsrefOverloaded.overload` (Static) and `().overload` (regular). It's a strange programming model since `builtin`, `obj`, and `x` appear to be same in both contexts... is there a reference page to learn of this behavior?

Comment: I'm guessing `builtin` could break encapsulation if available from outside the class definition. You could do things to the class that break invariants, which would cause class methods to no longer work correctly. But again, just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

`builtin` cares about where it's called from for some reason - it works properly if called from within the class itself (thanks @CrissLuengo). The following is an imperfect workaround

```matlab
classdef Dog
    methods
        function varargout = subsref(obj, x)
            [varargout{1:nargout}] = subsref_overloaded(obj, x);
            if ~isempty(varargout) && varargout{1} == "special token"
                [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', obj, x);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

```matlab
function varargout = subsref_overloaded(obj, x)
    if % your cond here
        % your logic here
    else
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = "special token";
    end
end
```

Better alternatives / explanations welcome.